# Write a function called circle that takes a turtle, t, and radius, r, as param

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
def polygon(t,length,n):
   for i in range(n):
      t.fd(length)
      t.lt(360/n)
   print(t)

polygon(bob,30,15)

turtle.mainloop()
```

How can I make a circle by calling polygon function?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like homework.

Comment: @HannounYassir, is that a valid reason to close the question given the [It is okay to ask about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/5771269) community policy?  The post shows the work done so far to solve the problem and is only slightly lacking in the description of the difficulty trying to solve it.  Which question guidelines are you working from?

Comment: @cdlane to me giving an answer to homework might do more harm than good to students. That being said, I think it is okay to help if a reasonable enough attempt to solve the problem was made.

Answer (score 1):

You already have written the correct code to produce a circle.  In the view of turtle's own `circle()` method, a circle is just a polygon with 60 sides (fewer if the circle is small.)  I.e. it's about perception and how many sides do you need before you can't tell the difference.

```
import turtle

def polygon(t, length, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(360 / n)

bob = turtle.Turtle()

bob.penup()
bob.sety(-270)
bob.pendown()

polygon(bob, 30, 60)

turtle.mainloop()
```

[image]

Your problem now is to control the drawing of the polygon/circle to produce it with a specific radius.  Your `length` parameter doesn't map to a radius as the circle is coming out way too large.  Here `length` represents 1/60 (1/n) of the circumference and we know that:

> `circumference = 2 * math.pi * radius`

We can calculate, in our `circle(t, radius)` function, what `length` needs to be given `radius` (i.e. `circumference/n`), and call `polygon(t, length, n)` with these parameters.  Here's a visual comparison drawing a radius 100 circle with turtle's `circle()` method (red) and drawing it with the solution I just described (blue):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import turtle
bob=turtle.Turtle()
bob.color('green', 'cyan')
bob.begin_fill()
def polygon(t,length, n):
    for i in range(n):
        bob.forward(length)
        bob.left(360/n)

import math
def circle(t, r):
        circum= 2*math.pi*r
        n= int(circum/10)+1
        length= circum/n
        polygon(t,length, n)

circle(bob, 100)
bob.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```